# Can we use "dotnet run" for running ASPnet Core application without project files and only with binaries

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, .net-core

Can we use "dotnet run" or any other cli command for running ASPnet Core application without project files and only with binaries in my local machine(not server), configs and executables.

my application is in AspnetCore 2.2 and .netframework 4.6.1

So I have the binaries, and I want to run the application using those binaries and I do not have the project files or solution file with projects.

I know this is possible as few-many years back I had done it using Visual studio 2015 exe, but thru command line  or so and ran the application using only binaries, just that it was .Net framework application, And I forgot how I did it.

My application is also configured to run using IIS Express, so I would also appreciate if I get to know if I could run using binaries with IIS using CLI.

Comment: Yes. Just execute `dotnet some.dll`  I suggest you check the tutorials, especially the publishing and deployment steps. In .NET Core 3.x a new option is to publish to [a single-file executable](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/MakingATinyNETCore30EntirelySelfcontainedSingleExecutable.aspx) you can execute directly.

Comment: If you deploy to IIS in-process though, you don't  need to run the executable. IIS will start the application when needed

Comment: well yes dotnet command works, but my app uses both  AspnetCore 2.2 and .netframework 4.6.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.

You can always use the help:

```sh
dotnet --help
```

```sh
Usage: dotnet [runtime-options] [path-to-application] [arguments]

...

path-to-application:
  The path to an application .dll file to execute.
```

Which describes its usage as:

```
dotnet your.file.dll
```

**EDIT 1:**
The `*.runtimeconfig.dev.json` usually has the following contents:

```
{
  "runtimeOptions": {
    "additionalProbingPaths": [
      "C:\\Users\\USERNAME\\.dotnet\\store\\|arch|\\|tfm|",
      "C:\\Users\\USERNAME\\.nuget\\packages",
      "C:\\Program Files\\dotnet\\sdk\\NuGetFallbackFolder"
    ]
  }
}
```

*Note: you need to replace **USERNAME** with your own username.*

and the `*.runtimeconfig.json`:

```
{
  "runtimeOptions": {
    "tfm": "netcoreapp2.2",
    "framework": {
      "name": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.App",
      "version": "2.2.0"
    },
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried with dotnet command issue is it needs to have project.runtimeconfig.dev.json updated , but I am using aspnetcore2.2 and net461, I am not sure how do I set the runtime config